# Use .htacess RewriteCond for all subdirectories of a subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, subdomain

How would I use a RewriteCond for all subdirectories of my subdomain

Example: `test.example.com/folder1/page1.php` -> `code.example/folder1/page1.php` (showing test.example.com/folder1/page1.php in the address bar)

I'm currently using:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://code.example.com/$1 [CO=cookie:%1:.example.com:126144000:/,P]
```

and that does what I want for `test.example.com/page2.php` -> `code.example.com/page2.php` (showing test.example.com/page2.php in the address bar)
but when I do `test.example.com/folder1/page1.php` -> `code.example.com/folder1/page1.php` I see code.example.com/folder1/page1.php (which I do **NOT** want)